# How to configure ESLint to add an empty line between same-level JSX blocks?

Tags: jsx, eslint

Is there a configuration option in ESLint or any other tool that can automatically add an empty line between JSX blocks that are at the same level?

For example, consider the following JSX code:

```
<div>
  <Hello />
  <Hello firstName="John" />
  <Hello firstName="John" lastName="Smith" />
</div>
```

Is it possible to automatically format the code to achieve the following:

```
<div>
  <Hello />

  <Hello firstName="John" />

  <Hello firstName="John" lastName="Smith" />
</div>
```

I'm looking for a solution that can help maintain a consistent and readable code style by adding an empty line between same-level JSX blocks. It would be great if this could be achieved through a configuration option or a plugin in ESLint or any other tool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `react/jsx-newline` have to be set to `"error"` without any additional params like:

```
"react/jsx-newline": ["error"],
```

and it works as expected.

In case of problems - you need to check whether there is no conflict with `prettier` formatter configuration.